# Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). Useing explode

Tags: laravel

I'm converting an explode array to a string using laravel. But the error says my variable is not an array. What is the wrong in my code?. Thanks in advance

```
$useroleid = auth()->user()->role_id;
$userroleall = UserRole::find($useroleid);
$userrole = explode(',', $userroleall->access);
$sqlmenu= "";

foreach ($userrole as $value) {
     $sqlmenu = "'".$value."',";
 }
$sqlmenu = substr($sqlmenu,0,-1);
```

the output must be like this:

'admin','guest','super_admin'

Comment: What's the output of `dd($userroleall->access)` if you place it before the `$userrole = ...` line?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to concatenate the values in `$userrole` to `$sqlmenu`? If so, you might want to change the statement in your foreach to:

```
$sqlmenu .= "'".$value."',";
```

Note the concat assignment operator (`.=`).

Answer (score 0):

you can use implode method like this :

```
$useroleid = auth()->user()->role_id;
$userroleall = UserRole::find($useroleid);
$sqlmenu= $userroleall->implode('access',',');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to rejoin a string after you exploded it? Why not just directly do

```
$sqlmenu = $userroleall->access
```

instead of exploding the string and then rejoining it again?

Comment: if i did that the output will be like
$sqlmenu = admin,guest,super-admin

I want the output is like this
$sqlmenu = 'admin,'guest','super-admin'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Will it move if I write like this?

```
$useroleid = auth()->user()->role_id;
$userroleall = UserRole::find($useroleid);
$sqlmenu= "";
foreach ($userrole as $value) {
 $value = explode(',', $userroleall->access);
 $sqlmenu = "'".$value."',";
}
$sqlmenu = substr($sqlmenu,0,-1);
```

Comment: If I did that the next error will be "Undifine $userrole"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like :

```
$useroleid = auth()->user()->role_id;
$userroleall = UserRole::find($useroleid);
$userrole = explode(' ', $userroleall->access);
```